# use fgetc reading newline character but error in macOS

Tags: c, macos

My code needs to use a lot of `fgetc(inp)`.

It doesn't have any problem in windows, but in macOS the program will error out.

I found that the problem is caused by the inconsistency of the number of characters in the newline character in both systems:
macOS just `\n`, windows is `\r\n`

So I created a new function to replace `fgetc(inp)` which reads newline characters

```
void getwhite() {
    int white = fgetc(inp);
    if (isspace(white) == 0) {
        fseek(inp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected, still works fine in windows, macOS still gives errors

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What error?  windows use `\r\n` line endings and mac, I am guessing, `\n`

Comment: Your function can't be used with `stdin`. If you ever want to use it with `stdin` use the [`ungetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ungetc) function instead of seeking.

Comment: @AllanWind Your guessing right, it's `\n` like on linux – *nowadays*, though, quite a few years ago macOS switched away from single `\r` that had been used before.

Comment: Open the file in `"t"` mode. Both characters will be read in `"b"` mode.

Comment: I'd just read a character, check if it is equal to `'\r'` and if so get next character; if equal to `'\n'` then ignore having read `'\r'` before, otherwise `unget` that character and convert the previously read `'\r'` to `'\n'` – that way you'd remain compatible even to old files written by a early macOS version (see comment above).

Comment: @WeatherVane `"t"` is a MSVC extension. Text-mode is normally the default mode unless `"b"` is specified.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I now see the C Standard mentions (among others) `"r"` and `"rb"` but not `"rt"`. For `"r"` it says *open text file for reading*.

Comment: The [Microsoft C runtime documentation for `fseek()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fseek-fseeki64?view=msvc-170) explains the limitations of it on text files.

Comment: You should post examples of offending code that have a different behavior on windows and macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `fseek()`, you should use `ungetc()` to push back the byte read from the stream:

```
int getwhite() {
    int c = fgetc(inp);
    if (!isspace(c)) {
        ungetc(c, inp);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Regarding the handling of line endings on windows and other systems: for legacy reasons, windows still uses CR LR sequences to indicate end of lines in text files and the C library translates these sequences *transparently* into a single `'\n'` byte for programs that read files as text, either with `fopen()` or lower level `open()` interfaces.

This makes file offsets tricky to use because the number of bytes read from the file may be different from the offset in bytes into the file, which cannot be retrieved with standard functions: the `long` returned by `ftell()` for streams open in text mode is only meaningful as a number to pass to `fseek()` for `SEEK_SET` mode on the same file open in text mode. Seeking with a non zero offset in `SEEK_CUR` and `SEEK_END` modes on a text stream has undefined behavior, as specified in the C Standard:

> **7.21.9.2 The `fseek` function**
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include 
> int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence);
> ```
>
> **Description**
> [...]
>
> For a text stream, either `offset` shall be zero, or `offset` shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function on a stream associated with the same file and `whence` shall be `SEEK_SET`.

If you need to rely on file offsets, you should open files in binary mode and handle the line endings explicitly in your own code.

Apple operating systems used to represent line endings as a single CR byte, but switched to a single NL byte more than 10 years ago, when they adopted the Mach unix compatible kernel.